# Django REST API Testing - How to test a utility module using requests to call API endpoints?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-testing

I'm using djangorestframework 3.11.0 for my development.  I have a utility module with pre and post data processing that currently interacts with the API endpoints using the python requests library.

In my test setup, I have done the following:

1. Create a mock user object
2. Create a token corresponding to the mock user object
3. Setup APIClient and force authenticate the mock user object

The tests with direct evaluation of API endpoint result through the APIClient all passed.  However the tests evaluating my utility module all failed with "Unauthorized."  What is the correct approach to address this type of testing?